# Running bash script in cron

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have the following bash script:

```
!/bin/bash
# script to send simple email 
#Wait 5 seconds
#sleep 05
# email subject
SUBJECT="SUBJECT"
# Email To ?
EMAIL="EMAIL"
# Email text/message
MYIP=$(curl http://ipecho.net/plain)
LASTIP=$(head -n 1 /home/ubuntu/myip.txt)
echo "Last IP:" $LASTIP
echo "Current IP:" $MYIP
#Check if IPs are the same
if [[ "$MYIP" == "$LASTIP" ]]; then
        echo "IP hasn't changed. Do nothing."
else
        sendemail -f $EMAIL -t $EMAIL -u $SUBJECT -m $MYIP -s smtp.gmail.com -o tls=yes -xu username -xp password
        echo $MYIP > myip.txt
fi
```

When I try to run it in the command line, it works perfectly. The problem starts when I include it in "crontab -e" like this: "* * * * * /home/ubuntu/myip.sh".

Then it does not work. Seem to be that the sendmail is not functioning properly.
When I do a: tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
Sep 18 21:48:02 gpuserver sendmail[18665]: r8J1m1gO018665: from=ubuntu, size=314, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201309190148.r8J1m1gO018665@gpuserver>, relay=ubuntu@localhost
Sep 18 21:48:02 gpuserver sendmail[18665]: r8J1m1gO018665: to=ubuntu, ctladdr=ubuntu (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30314, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What sendmail are you using?

Comment: Is the `e` in `sendemail` a typo in the real script, or just a copy error here?

Comment: Is cron configured to send the output of cron jobs?

Comment: Do you set any environment variables in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` that affect `sendmail`? Cron jobs don't run your profile.

Comment: the e in sendemail is correct! (installed through apt-get install sendemail)

Comment: @Barmar I have not set any variables.

Comment: @JonLin I don't think so, unless it is set by default

Comment: @user314104 latest in ubuntu repository

Comment: @user314104 do you have postfix or sendmail or some mail server installed?

Comment: /I/ do, as I have exim locally, but /I'm/ not the one experiencing the problem, @Wigiri is.  I ask because sendmail (not sendemail) is the process showing the error, as it tries to connect to the local system to deliver it.

Comment: From the shell, do a `which sendemail` and record the full path. Use the full path instead of just `sendemail`. Similarly with `curl` and `head`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script from the command line you are utilizing your current environment. Cron doesn't have that info ... So what you should do from the command line is:

```
env > me
```

Then edit the script and include ./me at the start of the script. That way your cron task will run with the same environment.

Comment: I think you mean `. ./me`. If you don't use the `.` command, the script will be run in a subshell and the variables won't be set in the script. Also, you need to add `export` commands to all the assignments.

Comment: There's another potential issue with this: `env > me` doesn't quote the values if they contain spaces.

Comment: not working. Added ./me to teh beginning of the file, and ran env > me , still showing the same issue. I have the feeling it has something to do with sendmail profile for root. Tried several solutions without any avail (especially because of sendemail, which is just a script for sendmail)

Comment: I think you misunderstood - what you need to do is run the env command first to get a copy of the current settings of your shell environment variables when logged in saved into the file ./me Then read the contents of me into your cron script using vim or your favorite text editor so all the environment variables are set in the script before you try to run sendmail

Answer (score 0):

When a cron prints something to stdout or stderr, cron itself tries to send a report by e-mail. Since you probably don't have system-wide e-mail configured, this is probably where the error message in syslog is coming from.

To prevent cron from sending any mail, make sure your script and any commands it spawns don't output anything to stdout or stderr. An easy way to do this is to add "&>/dev/null" to your cron line.

You can also add 'MAILTO=""' at the beginning of your crontab.

This all documented in the man pages for cron/crontab (man -k cron).